# Can't serialize read only field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize read only field (perform get request and view all objects)

**Problem:** i don't see read_only_fields in response:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cameras/

```
[ // no 'proc_id', 'path_frames'
    {
        "id": 1,
        "building": 3,
        "name": "1",
        "url": "1",
        "zoneIdX": 1,
        "zoneIdY": 1
    }
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CameraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Camera
        fields = ('id', 'building', 'name', 'url', 'zone_id_x', 'zone_id_y')
        read_only_fields = ('proc_id', 'path_frames')
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data=validated_data)
        return instance
```

**view.py**

```
class CameraView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CameraSerializer
    queryset = Camera.objects.all()

    def get_camera_create_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return self.serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = CameraSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        user = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CameraSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    ``Serializer`` for ``User`` ..
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name' ,'security_question', 'security_question_answer', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff')
        read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'security_question': {'write_only': True},
            'security_question_answer': {'write_only': True},
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

You need to add all fields in the `fields` tuple.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
class CameraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Camera
        fields = ('id', 'building', 'name', 'url', 'zone_id_x', 'zone_id_y', 'proc_id', 'path_frames')
        read_only_fields = ('proc_id', 'path_frames')
```

- Add all the fields that you want to see from your model  in the **fields = ('','',...)**.
- The **read_only_fields** attribute it's a way to give properties to your model's serializer, it doesn't add fields to your model's serializer